# Questions regarding performance of swap

Tags: c++

I have three questions regarding swapping, most likely pretty basic to you.

(1) With regards to two same type STL containers `a` and `b`, both operations below would work

```
swap(a,b);
a.swap(b);
```

I understand that the second is specialized for the container (e.g., only involves a number of iterator swaps) while the first is a global algorithm meant to work with generic datatypes and performs an internal copy-construct.

My question is if I write the first, will the compiler use the second regardless, or do I have to be careful to check if an appropriate specialization exists?

(2) Would `swap(a,b)` result in the same performance with `swap(b,a)`?  If a copy-construct is involved and the objects are of considerably different size, I suspect it may matter?

(3) In cases where the overloaded operator `==` exists and is relatively fast, checking for `a == b` before swapping would make sense so as to avoid unnecessary operations.  Does `std::swap` apply this check first, or does it perform the operation regardless?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The global `swap` template is specialized for each of the standard library types that supports `swap`; the specialization calls the member `swap`.
2. There should be no difference between `swap(a, b)` and `swap(b, a)`. (I can imagine perverse types where it would matter, but that would never occur in practice).
3. No, `std::swap`  typically doesn't check for equality. In many cases that would be slower than just doing the swap.

Comment: Doesn't this all depend on the specific implementation of the STL? I don't think you can derive any of this from the standard.

Comment: Number 3 might be implementation dependent. 1 is explicitly required.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response.